# Remove parent folder from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Tags: php, request-uri

I want to remove the first folder outputted by $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

```
// I use it as language switcher in my website, here's how it works:

<?php $currenturl=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<a href="https://mysite.com/<?php echo $currenturl ?>">United States</a>
<a href="https://mysite.com/ca<?php echo $currenturl ?>">Canada</a>
<a href="https://mysite.com/br<?php echo $currenturl ?>">Brasil</a>
```

The problem is, in Canada for example, it outputs:

https://mysite.com/ca/ca/mypage

It should be

https://mysite.com/ca/mypage

Comment: I can't see the out put when clicked on the link it simply says unable to connect

Comment: Yeah it's just to illustrate, take a close look at the link hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **`str_replace`**

```
<?php 

$currenturl=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$currenturl=str_replace('/ca','',$currenturl); // I have added it here

?>

<a href="https://mysite.com/<?php echo $currenturl ?>">United States</a>
<a href="https://mysite.com/ca<?php echo $currenturl ?>">Canada</a>
<a href="https://mysite.com/br<?php echo $currenturl ?>">Brasil</a>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, yet so simple! (accepting answer in 6 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

well, I think you are trying to get the filename of a path instead of removing the first folder.
try the following code:

```
$currenturl=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is provided by php, and it's not something that you can simply remove from your htaccess file. You need to remove it in php:

```
<?php $currenturl=preg_replace('#(/[a-z]{2})?(/.*)#','${2}',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use slightly modified example from Shankar Damodaran -

```
<?php
    $currenturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $languge_folder  = array('/en', '/ru', '/ua');
    $currenturl_en = str_replace($languge_folder,'',$currenturl); 
    $currenturl_ru = str_replace($languge_folder,'',$currenturl);
    $currenturl_ua = str_replace($languge_folder,'',$currenturl);
?>
          <select id="select-language" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
             <option value="/ua/<?php echo $currenturl_ua; ?>"  selected="selected">Ukrainian</option>
             <option value="/ru/<?php echo $currenturl_ru; ?>" >Russian</option>
             <option value="/en/<?php echo $currenturl_en; ?>" >English</option>
          </select>
```